# Apple will enforce HTTPs starting Jan 1, 2017: what about localhost?

Tags: ios, http, https

Apple is about to enforce only HTTPs request from iOS apps starting Jan, 1, 2017.
I was wondering whether to post this question here but I've been looking around and it seems like either many developers dig their head in the sand waiting for the hammer to fall or people are not aware of the impact of this change.

Personally, my main concern is regarding localhost requests; does anyone know whether HTTPs will be enforced for local requests (localhost or 127.0.0.1)?

Thanks,

Comment: After January you can still disable ATS but you need to,provide details on review as to why you need to disable ATS

Comment: Why would you need to make http requests to localhost from an iOS app? That means you are connecting to the same iOS device your app is running on.

Comment: We have a local server running on the device which we need to connect to